# How to consume async a service with a client that implements ClientBase interface?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have this contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculadoraService
    {
        // TODO: Add your service operations here
        [OperationContract()]
        int Add(int num1, int num2);

        [OperationContract()]
        Task<int> AddAsync(int num1, int num2);
    }
```

I have this implementation:

```
public class CalculadoraService : ICalculadoraService
    {
        public int Add(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 + num2;
        }

        public async Task<int> AddAsync(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 + num2;

        }
    }
```

In my client side I have this proxy that implements the ClientBase interface:

```
class WCFCalculadoraServiceProxy : ClientBase<ICalculadoraService>, ICalculadoraService
    {
        public int Add(int num1, int num2)
        {
            //Lo que hace es llamar al método del servicio.
            return base.Channel.Add(num1, num2);
        }

        public Task<int> AddAsync(int num1, int num2)
        {
            //Lo que hace es llamar al método del servicio.
            return base.Channel.AddAsync(num1, num2);
        }
    }
```

And I have a console application in my client that use this proxy:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WCFCalculadoraServiceProxy miProxy = new WCFCalculadoraServiceProxy();
            try
            {
                addAsync(miProxy);
            }
            catch
            {
                //TODO
            }
            finally
            {
                miProxy.Close();
            }
        }

        private static async void addAsync(WCFCalculadoraServiceProxy paramProxy)
        {
            int resultado = await paramProxy.AddAsync(1, 2); //is reached
            Console.WriteLine("Service is host at " + DateTime.Now.ToString()); // is not reached
            Console.WriteLine("El resultado de sumar 1 y 2 es: " + resultado);
            Console.WriteLine("Host is running... Press <Enter> key to stop");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the console does not show the result. It reaches the first line of the method AddAsync, but after a few seconds, the console is closed, so the text of the first writeline is not shown.

I would like to know how to solve this problem and to know what is the correct way to consume a service asynchronously from a client that implements the ClientBase interface.

If I add a service reference it works, but I would like to know why my solution does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to **ClientBase** interface.

Looking at your code, the **await** keyword will cause the code in the method **addAsync** to execute on a different child thread, while the main thread will continue with the rest of the code.

However, there is nothing else for the main thread to do; the very next statement that will get executed is closing of the proxy after which the thread will exit. In other words, your program is over even before the statement **'paramProxy.AddAsync(1, 2);'** would return so the **Console.Writeline** methods are never executed.

You can try adding a **Thread.Sleep** call after **addAsync(miProxy)** call in your **Main** method, and it should allow sufficient time for the child thread to complete.